# Jquery Snippet Error Chimp

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a button from Chimp.net that when you click on it opens an iframe with a pop up window, but I have an error in the code and I can not recognize it.
Can anybody see the problem?
This is the page where I am getting the code:
http://blog.chimp.net/chimp-custom-widget/

Code:

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://chimp.net/widget/js/loader.js?NzYyNSxtaW5pLHRlYWwsUGluayBTaGlydCBEYXkgMjAxNixHcm91cA%3D%3D" id="chimp-button-script" data-hide-button="true" data-script-id="oriol"> </script>
<h1>Button</h1>
<div id="custom-chimp-button" width="200px" height="200px" style="background: red; cursor: pointer; padding: 10px; margin: 10px;"><strong>Button</strong><br> You can click on this div! It'll open the form.</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#custom-chimp-button").on("click", function() {
            var frame = document.getElementById("chimp-form-oriol");
            var content = frame.contentWindow; content.postMessage("open-chimp-frame", "*");
            frame.style.opacity = 1;
            frame.style.display = "block";
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Developer tools work wonders for such things. F12, go to the "Console", and there you go. Something like "Error: 123 Something happened line:45"

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `jquery.min.js` reference on your page I guess. Please add it and see what you get.

Here on SO; iframe are not allowed so it won't show up in this code snippet.

```js
$(document).ready(function() { $("#custom-chimp-button").on("click", function() { var frame = document.getElementById("chimp-form-oriol"); var content = frame.contentWindow; content.postMessage("open-chimp-frame", "*"); frame.style.opacity = 1; frame.style.display = "block"; }); });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://chimp.net/widget/js/loader.js?NzYyNSxtaW5pLHRlYWwsUGluayBTaGlydCBEYXkgMjAxNixHcm91cA%3D%3D" id="chimp-button-script" data-hide-button="true" data-script-id="oriol"> </script>

<h1>Button</h1>
<div id="custom-chimp-button" width="200px" height="200px" style="background: red; cursor: pointer; padding: 10px; margin: 10px;"> <strong>Button</strong><br> You can click on this div! It'll open the form.</div>
```

Comment: How does `I guess` constitute an answer ? Seems more like a comment

Comment: @charlietfl - that's very true. I couldn't able to test it here on SO. So i left it for OP to test above changes at his end.